# Createloader not being called

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-loadermanager

I'm facing a peculiar problem, I have two separate activities, but if required both might call one fragment for inserting some data in local db. So since the fragment is common I  kept everything as it should be. It working well and good in the 1st activity. But to my utter dismay when I try to do the same thing from the other activity it never works.

I debugged it and found that whenever I'm calling the initloader method, it didn't go to the createLoader method. It doesn't matter whether I use force load or not it doesn't work, but it comes down directly to the loadfinished method.

I'm pretty confused why will it work for the 1st activity and why will it not work for the second, anyway it is a fragment i can call it from any where correct?

EDIT:

Two activities opening the same fragment, inside the fragment there is a loader to insert some data in local db using a asynctask loader. Since its the same fragment loader id is same, but I am doing

```
getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().destroyLoader(loader.getId());
```

at the end of loadfinshed so that loader id is removed. And its not the case that the 1st activity is always started at first, even if I go the second one it doesn't work, but if I go for the other one it works.

Createloader is not called but goes directly to loadfinshed.

Any hint what might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using the same value for the loader ID in the second activity as in the first?

Comment: I'm calling the loader from the fragment itself, so whatever be it,the fragment will use the same loader id obviously.

Comment: It sounds like on the second `initLoader` call, it's picking up the previous `Loader` so `createLoader` isn't getting called.  Check in the debugger if the second `getLoaderManager` call is getting the same `LoaderManager` instance as the first call. It shouldn't, but if for some reason it is, that `LoaderManager` already has a `Loader` instance with that ID and that's why `createLoader` isn't getting called.

Comment: Kindly check the EDIT..